# Use greylisting only if SPF fails

Tags: postfix, spf, greylisting

I have noticed that more and more people using the DNS based SPF records and I want to enhance my spam filter.
I am using SPF and greylisting after each other and my idea would be to use only greylisting if SPF fails or similar.

I have searched the internet for a soluation, but it seems that most people only wish a new feature for example for sqlgrey doing it, which is being declined by the author, because it isn't the main task of a greylisting tool.

Has anyone such filter chain running and can help me out?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your idea was implemented in [milter-greylist](http://hcpnet.free.fr/milter-greylist), another milter to support greylisting. In their [features page](http://hcpnet.free.fr/milter-greylist/#features), it says

> Starting with version 1.1.3, milter-greylist is able to use libspf_alt to check SPF records. SPF records are DNS objects that tell the whole Internet which server(s) can legally send e-mail from a domain.
>
> **Using SPF records, milter-greylist will avoid greylisting any mail that comes from an SPF-compliant server. This feature is optionnal and requires libspf_alt**
>
> Starting with 1.1.10, libspf (James Couzens's version) is also supported. libpsf2 is supported starting with version 1.7.2.

The feature *auto whitelisting for spf-compliant-server* is enabled by default. You can disabled it by adding `nospf` in its configuration.

Comment: supporting v6 and multi mx sync! perfect thanks!